# How to check whether the user has provided an input or not?

Tags: c++

I am trying to develop a program in which I need to check whether the user gave input or not at first. If the user gives no input, a block of statements have to be executed and if the user gives input some other statements are executed. Using getche() or getchar() requires you to provide input, but I need the program to execute even if no input is fed. Is it possible to do this?

Basically I decided that I will take in an input from the user and run a segment of code but if no input is provided I will run another segment and end of of program.
Cause I don't want to print any messages to the user like `cout<<"Do you wish to continue?(y/n)"; cin>>choice;`. Instead I want the program to under stand by itself that the user dosen't want to continue. My program algorithm looks like this-

```
1.Check whether the user gave an input or not.If yes execute <2> else execute <3>
2. Receive input from user. Execute a set of operations. Then again go to <1>
3. Display message "Application shutting down". Go to <4>.
4.End
```

Answer (score 2):

> How to check whether the user has provided an input or not?

### This is ill defined and operating system and computer specific.

The  [`std::cin` stream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) is documented; it is some [std::istream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream). Of course you need to read a [good C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html), and you should be aware that it could be redirected (e.g. in some [Unix pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29)).

Read also the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf). I am not sure that users are mentioned there.

On Linux, to wait for some input, consider using system calls like [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) with `STDIN_FILENO`

On Linux, you might use [readline(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html) to get *interactively editable* input from your user.

On Windows, you could use the [WinAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/) in your C++ code.

You could also code a GUI application, e.g. with [FLTK](https://fltk.org/) or [Qt](https://qt.io/). Then "user input" has a very different meaning (and could just involve your computer mouse).

You could also code a [Web application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application) in C++ (e.g. using [libonion](https://coralbits.com/static/onion/)). Or a [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) application. Then again, user input means something related to the [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) protocol.

You could also program a [RaspberryPi](https://raspberrypi.org/) in C++. In many cases, there might be no users at all. Probably, many [ATM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_teller_machine) are coded in C++, and most of the time they have no users at all. Your [computer mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_mouse) micro-controller or your [microwave oven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_oven) could be coded in C++ too and could have several users. A lot of [embedded software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_software) in [IoT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_things) devices is coded in C++ (or in C). See the European [CHARIOT](https://www.chariotproject.eu/) project (and [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report).

You might even make something with an [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/) programmed in C++

Your car probably has millions of C++ lines (and probably so do [ICBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercontinental_ballistic_missile)s). Who is your car's user? You, or the company in charge of maintaining your car (and uploading its firmware)?

Some C++ programs (think of a web server coded in C++) could have many thousands of simultaneous users.

You could compile your C++ code with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) and build your software using [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/). All of these are [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) and coded in C++. Could you please define who is their user? You'll learn a lot by downloading their C++ code and studying it!